# I want to fetch records from mongodb using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a rentals collection with fields `userid` (refering to users collectiion) and `vehicle_id`(refering to vehicle collection), in vehicle, further have fields like `brand_id`(reference to brands collection), `model_id`, `type_id` etc.

I want to fetch records from rentals table with username from user collection, vehicle name from vehicle collection and further required brand name from brands table etc

```
return Rentals
.find({ bookedBy: user_id, isCompleted: 'true' })
.populate('bookedBy')
.populate('vehicle_id')
.populate('brand_id')
.then(function (rentals) {}
```

Comment: What have you tried abd what is the issue you are facing? Please post the error message, if any.

Comment: Error: In `.populate("brand_id")`, attempting to populate an attribute that do
sn't exist